# bootstrap nav bar search advanced search box align vertically

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap

```css
.dropdown.dropdown-lg .dropdown-menu {
                                    margin-top: -1px;
                                    padding: 6px 20px;
                                }
                                .input-group-btn .btn-group {
                                    display: flex !important;
                                }
                                .btn-group .btn {
                                    border-radius: 0;
                                    margin-left: -1px;
                                }
                                .btn-group .btn:last-child {
                                    border-top-right-radius: 4px;
                                    border-bottom-right-radius: 4px;
                                }
                                .btn-group .form-horizontal .btn[type="submit"] {
                                  border-top-left-radius: 4px;
                                  border-bottom-left-radius: 4px;
                                }
                                .form-horizontal .form-group {
                                    margin-left: 0;
                                    margin-right: 0;
                                }
                                .form-group .form-control:last-child {
                                    border-top-left-radius: 4px;
                                    border-bottom-left-radius: 4px;
                                }

                                @media screen and (min-width: 768px) {
                                    #adv-search {
                                        width: 100px;
                                        
                                    }
                                    .dropdown.dropdown-lg {
                                        position: static !important;
                                    }
                                    .dropdown.dropdown-lg .dropdown-menu {
                                        min-width: 500px;
                                    }
                                }
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<nav class="navbar navbar-default">
  <div class="container-fluid">
    <!-- Brand and toggle get grouped for better mobile display -->
    <div class="navbar-header">
      <button type="button" class="navbar-toggle collapsed" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#bs-example-navbar-collapse-1">
        <span class="sr-only">Toggle navigation</span>
        <span class="icon-bar"></span>
        <span class="icon-bar"></span>
        <span class="icon-bar"></span>
      </button>
      <a class="navbar-brand" href="#">Brand</a>
    </div>

    <!-- Collect the nav links, forms, and other content for toggling -->
    <div class="collapse navbar-collapse" id="bs-example-navbar-collapse-1">
      <ul class="nav navbar-nav">
        <li class="active"><a href="#">Link <span class="sr-only">(current)</span></a></li>
        <li><a href="#">Link</a></li>
        <li class="dropdown">
          <a href="#" class="dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown" role="button" aria-expanded="false">Dropdown <span class="caret"></span></a>
          <ul class="dropdown-menu" role="menu">
            <li><a href="#">Action</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">Another action</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">Something else here</a></li>
            <li class="divider"></li>
            <li><a href="#">Separated link</a></li>
            <li class="divider"></li>
            <li><a href="#">One more separated link</a></li>
          </ul>
        </li>
      </ul>
      
      <div class="navbar-form navbar-right input-group" id="adv-search">
                            <input type="text" class="form-control" placeholder="Search for ..." />
                            <div class="input-group-btn">
                                <div class="btn-group" role="group">
                                    <div class="dropdown dropdown-lg">
                                        <button type="button" class="btn btn-default dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown" aria-haspopup="true" aria-expanded="false"><span class="caret"></span></button>
                                        <div class="dropdown-menu dropdown-menu-right" role="menu">
                                            <form class="form-horizontal" role="form">
                                              <div class="form-group">
                                                <label for="filter" class="col-sm-2 control-label">Filter by</label>
                                                <div class="col-sm-10">
                                                    <select class="form-control">
                                                        <option value="0" selected>All Snippets</option>
                                                        <option value="1">Featured</option>
                                                        <option value="2">Most popular</option>
                                                        <option value="3">Top rated</option>
                                                        <option value="4">Most commented</option>
                                                    </select>
                                                </div>
                                              </div>
                                              <div class="form-group">
                                                <label for="contain" class="col-sm-2 control-label">Author</label>
                                                <div class="col-sm-10">
                                                    <input class="form-control" type="text" />
                                                </div>
                                              </div>
                                              <div class="form-group">
                                                <label for="contain">Contains the words</label>
                                                <div class="col-sm-10">
                                                    <input class="form-control" type="text" />
                                                </div>
                                              </div>
                                              <button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary"><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-search" aria-hidden="true"></span></button>
                                            </form>
                                        </div>
                                    </div>
                                    <button type="button" class="btn btn-primary"><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-search" aria-hidden="true"></span></button>
                                </div>
                            </div>
                        </div>
    </div><!-- /.navbar-collapse -->
  </div><!-- /.container-fluid -->
</nav>
```

bootstrap nav bar search advanced search box align vertically
**Note that** it worked for smaller devices but for desktop it wont display vertically.
show it in expand snippit mode.
i get the anvanced from bootsnipp.com

Answer (score 0):

```html
<html>
<head>
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
 <link rel="stylesheet" href="http://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.6/css/bootstrap.min.css">
          <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.12.4/jquery.min.js"></script>
          <script src="http://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.6/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
          <style type="text/css">
           .dropdown.dropdown-lg .dropdown-menu {
                                    margin-top: -1px;
                                    padding: 6px 20px;
                                }
                                .input-group-btn .btn-group {
                                    display: flex !important;
                                }
                                .btn-group .btn {
                                    border-radius: 0;
                                    margin-left: -1px;
                                }
                                .btn-group .btn:last-child {
                                    border-top-right-radius: 4px;
                                    border-bottom-right-radius: 4px;
                                }
                                .btn-group .form-horizontal .btn[type="submit"] {
                                  border-top-left-radius: 4px;
                                  border-bottom-left-radius: 4px;
                                }
                                .form-horizontal .form-group {
                                    margin-left: 0;
                                    margin-right: 0;
                                }
                                .form-group .form-control:last-child {
                                    border-top-left-radius: 4px;
                                    border-bottom-left-radius: 4px;
                                }

                                @media screen and (min-width: 768px) {
                                    #adv-search {
                                        width: 100px;
                                        
                                    }
                                    .dropdown.dropdown-lg {
                                        position: static !important;
                                    }
                                    .dropdown.dropdown-lg .dropdown-menu {
                                        min-width: 500px;
                                    }
                                }
          </style>
  </head>

    <body>
    <nav class="navbar navbar-default">
  <div class="container-fluid">
    <!-- Brand and toggle get grouped for better mobile display -->
    <div class="navbar-header">
      <button type="button" class="navbar-toggle collapsed" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#bs-example-navbar-collapse-1">
        <span class="sr-only">Toggle navigation</span>
        <span class="icon-bar"></span>
        <span class="icon-bar"></span>
        <span class="icon-bar"></span>
      </button>
      <a class="navbar-brand" href="#">Brand</a>
    </div>

    <!-- Collect the nav links, forms, and other content for toggling -->
    <div class="collapse navbar-collapse" id="bs-example-navbar-collapse-1">
      <ul class="nav navbar-nav">
        <li class="active"><a href="#">Link <span class="sr-only">(current)</span></a></li>
        <li><a href="#">Link</a></li>
        <li class="dropdown">
        <a href="#" class="dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown" role="button" aria-expanded="false">Dropdown <span class="caret"></span></a>
          <ul class="dropdown-menu" role="menu">
            <li><a href="#">Action</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">Another action</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">Something else here</a></li>
            <li class="divider"></li>
            <li><a href="#">Separated link</a></li>
            <li class="divider"></li>
            <li><a href="#">One more separated link</a></li>
          </ul>
        </li>
      </ul>
    <div class="navbar-form navbar-right input-group" id="adv-search">
                            <input type="text" class="form-control" placeholder="Search for ..." />
                            <div class="input-group-btn">
                                <div class="btn-group" role="group">
                                    <div class="dropdown dropdown-lg">
                                        <button type="button" class="btn btn-default dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown" aria-haspopup="true" aria-expanded="false"><span class="caret"></span></button>
                                        <div class="dropdown-menu dropdown-menu-right" role="menu">
                                            <form class="form-horizontal" role="form">
                                              <div class="form-group">
                                                <label for="filter" class="col-sm-2 control-label">Filter by</label>
                                                <div class="col-sm-10">
                                                    <select class="form-control">
                                                        <option value="0" selected>All Snippets</option>
                                                        <option value="1">Featured</option>
                                                        <option value="2">Most popular</option>
                                                        <option value="3">Top rated</option>
                                                        <option value="4">Most commented</option>
                                                    </select>
                                                </div>
                                              </div>
                                              <div class="form-group">
                                                <label for="contain" class="col-sm-2 control-label">Author</label>
                                                <div class="col-sm-10">
                                                    <input class="form-control" type="text" />
                                                </div>
                                              </div>
                                              <div class="form-group">
                                                <label for="contain" class="col-sm-2 control-label" >Contains the words</label>
                                                <div class="col-sm-10">
                                                    <input class="form-control" type="text" />
                                                </div>
                                              </div>
                                              <button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary"><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-search" aria-hidden="true"></span></button>
                                            </form>
                                        </div>
                                    </div>
                                    <button type="button" class="btn btn-primary"><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-search" aria-hidden="true"></span></button>
                                </div>
                            </div>
                        </div>
</body>
  </html>
```

You have not added `class="col-sm-2 control-label"` for that particular label.

Now it is vertically aligned.